# Is "contains himself" exactly the right phrase here?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

(James is about to leave a bar with a girl he knows Mark likes.)

> James grins at Mark, who's pissed but contains himself.

Is "contains himself" exactly the right phrase here to mean that Mark controls himself from exploding even though he really wants to?

Answer (score -1):

Well, **exactly** the right phrase is a matter of opinion, but the sentence is grammatical, clear, and it uses the phrase [contains himself](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/to+contain+oneself) correctly.